# JFreeChart xAxis as milliseconds

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart, epoch

in JFreeChart my date values are coming into my program in the form of long time in milliseconds. I therefore convert it to `RegularTimePeriod` class using `FixedMillisecond` class. Unfortunately, the chart I am displaying is still using the milliseconds as the xAxis values, rather than printing nice dates/days etc. toString method on `FixedMillisecond` class returns very nice, formatted string denoting day, hour, seconds etc. but it is not the case for the axis rendering. Is there a way to override this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - assuming you're using a `DateAxis`, you can set the `DateFormat`

```
DateAxis axis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
axis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss"));
```

Comment: Thank you, I have just encountered another problem. I have changed my ChartFactory to return the actual time series (I was using XYseries) so the axis looks good now. But, if I inssert points for two different years, the axix starts showing something like Jun3900 etc. Any ideas?